# Run function next frame (Not in update()) Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to run a block of code a certain amount of seconds after a 2D Collision. Currently, when the collision occurs it calls a function that loops over itself until a certain time is reached. The time is calculated using a time variable and adding `Time.deltaTime` each iteration.

This is the function

```
public void springBack(Collider2D collision, float timeCount) {
    if (timeCount > springReloadTime * 10) {
        Debug.Log("Springing Back!");

        timeCount = 0f;
    } else {
       timeCount = timeCount + Time.deltaTime;

       springBack(collision, timeCount);
    }
}
```

The issue occurs when I run this. Everything happens in one frame right after the collision instead of after a few seconds. If I could call the `springBack(collision, timeCount);` function on the next frame, this would work. When I looked it up, some people suggested using `yield return null;`, but since this isn't a loop it gives me this error here:

```
The body of 'playerMovement.springBack(Collider2D, float)' cannot be an iterator block because 'void' is not an iterator interface type
```

Is there another way to force it to run on the next frame? I could call it from the `update()` loop, but I think I can have multiple instances of this function running without it inferring with each other. If you need the values of some of the public variables (like `springReloadTime`), please ask.

Comment: You can use `yield` only in coroutines (which is also what you want to use for this): https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html

Comment: @UnholySheep, Thanks. I've replaced the void with `IEnumerator` and added the `yield return null;` before the `springBack(collision, timeCount);` line and it ran without error, and completion. Any ideas?

Comment: @JackStoller `StartCoroutine(springBack())`, `springBack` must return `IEnumerator` and inside this method implement your desired behaviour (it loks like you want to do it every n-th seconds, so you can do something like `while(isLooping) {springBack(); yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);}`. Be aware, that in that case you should store `WaitForSeconds` in property and then yield that property (`var awaiter = new WaitForSeconds(n); .... while() {yield return awaiter;}`). Using awaiter like this will not allocate memory everyTime, which is usefull especially in mobile development.

Comment: @PavelPájaHalbich Thanks! Could you post an answer?